# How to get ID from DB if user enters INT to text input using Ajax/PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm running a database with itemID's and a shelfnumber for every itemID..

As the user enters an itemID I want it to run through my database to get the shelfnumber using Ajax/PHP. Then post the shelfnumber back so the user can see where to find the item. (The items are in a room and are marked with unique ID's and shared shelfnumbers.) I need to use the onChange method (or anything similar) beacuse I want it to work like a tip/search engine. In other words automatic..

I'm totally new to ajax and I can't seem to get this to work at all.. No result is given and i'm at a roadblock right now.. Any form of help will be very appreciated

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#target').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'shelfid.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data:{ 
            itemID: $(this).val() 
        },
        success:function(response) {
            alert("Item: "+response.itemID+", Shelf: "+response.Hyllplacering);
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
    <body>
        <a>Enter Item ID 1:</a> 
        <input id="target" type="text" name="itemID" required />    
        <div id="hyllplacering">ENTER Shelfnumber here: </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") OR die(' Could not connect');
$db = mysql_select_db('book1', $con);
$itemID = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'itemID', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$query = "SELECT Hyllplacering from booking WHERE itemID = $itemID";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo json_encode(array('itemID' => $itemID, 'Hyllplacering' => $row['Hyllplacering']));
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting an alert at all?

Comment: You need validation or way the ajax calls or returning accordance to input ?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker No.. When I unfocus the input nothing happends at all.

Comment: Learn how to use `console` to log out any errors or data into the inspector of your browser such as firebug or Chrome Developer Tools

Comment: Yeah I will try to firebug it and post the result

Comment: @RobSchmuecker The console gave me ReferenceError: $ is not defined
 

$('#target').change(function() {

Comment: That means that the `$` sign of jQuery is not being defined which might mean you are not including the jQuery library correctly.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I've edited the code. No bugs anymore but still no result given..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is executed as soon as it is encountered. You bind the Event to an Element before it is available.
You need to wrap the script in a [`document.ready`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) body.

As the other answers mentioned you want to use the `success` callback instead of `done`.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#target').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'shelfid.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data:{ 
                itemID: $(this).val() 
            };
        })
        .success(function(response) {
            alert("Item: "+response.itemID+", Shelf: "+response.Hyllplacering);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This works! The input got sent to my PHP document.. It gave me null on the shelfid, but still closer then before!

Answer (score 0):

You may add a sentence in AJAX function

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'shelfid.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data:{ 
            itemID: $(this).val() 
        };
        success:function(data){
            console.info(data);
        }
    })
```

to monitor what your PHP responsed, it's more easy to check what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you incorrect to use the done method of the Ajax object. I am pretty sure you wont have your response available in that scope. Try to do it like..

```
$('#target').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'shelfid.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data:{ 
            itemID: $(this).val() 
        },
        success:function(response) {
            alert("Item: "+response.itemID+", Shelf: "+response.Hyllplacering);
        },
        error:function(response){
            alert('error '+response);
        };
    })
});
```

Comment: Still dosn't work.. No bugs in console using firebug and still no result at all

Comment: Have a look in the firebug net tab and see what the post/response tabs show for the request to shelfid.php. You might need to turn 'persist' on. Also try adding an error handler function (as per edit)

Comment: Yeah I manage to fix the problem using firebug. The alert works as it should right now. I will go on and find a way to make the response to an INT instead.